# Disable "Install app" icon in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to remove the below icon from the Chrome URL bar?

[image]

Comment: When does this dialogue appear? When you navigate to a specific website?

Comment: It shows on some pages like on YouTube.com for example.